# How do I setup a shared session between two users on my Ruby on Rails powered site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

The website that I'm building includes a section where two users can interact. I think I know how to do most of it, except the actual session sharing part. I'm using Ruby on Rails & Javascript (jquery), and I've got user login and session management all working okay. Would the best way to create a shared session be to have a SharedSession model, with accompanying database table, with participant1ID, participant2ID etc? Is there a better way? Thanks so much for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a model for shared session is good enough.